# SQLAlchemy create_engine connection string with Microsoft ODBC datasource User DSN

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, odbc, connection-string

Does anyone know how to pass connection string into create_engine function?
I use Window and has a ODBC datasource with DSN that set up by IT department.

My ODBC DSN connects to Postgres database.

Does anyone know the library or connection string to make this to work?

Note that I cannot ask them for the username and password to access the Postgres directly. I only can connect via ODBC only.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the `winreg` library.
Below is a function I adapted from Bart Jonk.
Original answer and function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66528870/11080806

```
from winreg import (ConnectRegistry, HKEY_CURRENT_USER, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, OpenKeyEx, QueryValueEx,)

def odbc_connection_string(odbc_dsn_name: str, system_dsn: bool = False):
    """
    Converts a windows ODBC DSN to a dsn
    that can be passed to sqlalchemy and used by psycopg2.

    It reads connection parameters from the Windows Registry.

    By: Bart Jonk on stackoverflow
    https://stackoverflow.com/users/11100064/bart-jonk
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/66528870/11080806

    Parameters
    -----
    odbc_dsn_name: str
        Name of the ODBC DSN to get connection details from.
    system_dsn: bool, default False
        If True look for DSN in system folder, otherwise look in current user folder.
    """
    # connect to registry
    if system_dsn:
        hreg = ConnectRegistry(None, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
    else:
        hreg = ConnectRegistry(None, HKEY_CURRENT_USER)
    # define key and open
    key = f"SOFTWARE\\ODBC\\ODBC.INI\\{odbc_dsn_name}"
    hkey = OpenKeyEx(hreg, key)

    # get hostname, port, sslmode, credentials from odbc registry
    hostname = QueryValueEx(hkey, "Servername")[0]
    # port_number = QueryValueEx(hkey, "Port")[0]
    # ssl_mode = QueryValueEx(hkey, "SSLmode")[0]
    database = QueryValueEx(hkey, "Database")[0]
    username = QueryValueEx(hkey, "UID")[0]
    password = QueryValueEx(hkey, "Password")[0]

    # set defaults for port number and SSL mode
    # if not port_number:
    #     port_number = "5432"
    # if not ssl_mode:
    #     ssl_mode = 'Prefer'

    # create connection string in sqlalchemy format
    return f"postgresql://{username}:{password}@{hostname}/{database}"
```

Answer (score 0):

The below worked for me:

```
engine=create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://user:password@DSNSTRING")
```